# "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" can't fix it

Tags: express

When I try to send a post request in express i have this error and I don't know how to fix it

```
POST /api/auth/login 500 118.471 ms - 421
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:663:11)        
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Михаил\Desktop\code\workout-app\wa-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Михаил\Desktop\code\workout-app\wa-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Михаил\Desktop\code\workout-app\wa-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
    at errorHandler (file:///C:/Users/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB/Desktop/code/workout-app/wa-server/app/middleware/error.middleware.js:10:7)
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\Михаил\Desktop\code\workout-app\wa-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Михаил\Desktop\code\workout-app\wa-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:326:13)
    at C:\Users\Михаил\Desktop\code\workout-app\wa-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Михаил\Desktop\code\workout-app\wa-server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
```

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pScq.png)

[auth controller 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCYXX.png)

[auth controller 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV3jm.png)

[auth controller 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzyvN.png)

[auth routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Jwx.png)

I was expecting

```
POST /api/auth/login 200 118.471 ms - 421
```

not 500

Comment: please add your login api code, instead of whole log trace.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I added pictures of auth controller and routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your login controller, you have if else, in if statement you are sending res.json and again after condition you are sending res.json again, and thats the issue remove line 28.

Basically res.json sends a response, so you cant send it twice.

Comment: That helped! Thank you so much! I I puzzeld over it for several hours! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome, please accept the answer if it helped @Mhl